# MVVMCross : Xamarin iOS - Bind ButtonClick inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross for my Xamarin project. I am using a button inside UICollectionViewCell, on click I want to navigate to another page. Is their a way to bind it to command in a view model and navigate to another page through view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I got it.

Need to do a DelayBind:

```
this.DelayBind(() => 
                {
                    var bSet = this.CreateBindingSet<Cell, ViewModel>();
                    set.Bind(Photo3Button).To(vm => vm.ClickCommand);
                    bSet.Apply();
                });
```